# Angular - How use $emit?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

when i call `{{callData}}` in my html, and result of `$scope.callData` doesn't work.
maybe my code is wrong ?
please help me to solved it

```js
 phonecatControllers.controller('PhoneListCtrl', 
  ['$scope', 'Phone', function($scope, Phone){
    $scope.phones = Phone.query();

  $scope.sortir = 'age';
  $scope.getCount = function(){
    return $scope.phones.length;
  };
  $scope.$emit('showData', {
    showData: $scope.getCount
  });
  }]);

  phonecatControllers.controller('PhoneDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'Phone',
  function($scope, $routeParams, Phone) {
      $scope.phone = Phone.get({phoneId: $routeParams.phoneId}, function(phone) {
       $scope.mainImageUrl = phone.images[0];
    });

  $scope.setImage = function(imageUrl) {
    $scope.mainImageUrl = imageUrl;
  }
  }]);

  phonecatControllers.controller('JumlahCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {

    $scope.$on('showData', function(event, obj){

        console.log(obj);
        $scope.callData = function(event){
          obj.showData();
        };
  })
  }]);
```

```html
<div>
  <span>jumlah : {{callData()}} </span>
</div>
```

why result of `$scope.callData` cannot popped out

Comment: $emit dispatches an event name upwards through the scope hierarchy. Who is the parent controller and who is the child?

Comment: Please elaborate your HTML a bit, as it is not clear about the controllers that which controller is attached to which part of your HTML. As mentioned, $emit track upwards through the hierarchy in order to find any listener. In case the controller dispatching the event is child controller and the controller listening the event is parent controller, you can use $scope.$emit, in case its is vice versa, you got to use $scope.$broadcast. The more apt and recommended way of doing controller communication is to use $rootScope.$emit as it will upwards till rootScope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd comment on the question if I could, but in the example you've posted, you didn't declare any [ng-controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController) directives on your div. So html have no idea about any angular functions at all.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <span>jumlah : {{callData()}} </span>
</div>
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.callData = function() {
        return 123;
    }
}
```

Here's a small jsFiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/5uu2cq6j/

Answer (score 1):

`$scope` is limited to its own controller. You need to emit on `$rootScope` level. Try changing

```
$scope.$emit('showData', {
   showData: $scope.getCount
});
```

to

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('showData', {
   showData: $scope.getCount
});
```

Comment: thank you, but it doesn't work.
{{callData()}} in my html not show.